# An ellipse intrinsically bound to any triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, conic-sections, geometric-construction

Given any triangle $\triangle ABC$, we build the hyperbole with foci in $A$ and $B$ and passing through $C$. The hyperbole always intersects the side of the triangle that is opposite to the vertex through which it pass in two points $D$ and $E$.

[image]

Similarly, we can build other two hyperboles, one with foci in $A$ and $C$ and passing through $B$ (red), and one with foci in $B$ and $C$ and passing through $A$ (green), obtaining other $2$ couples of points $F$, $G$ and $H$, $I$.

[image]

My conjecture is that

> **The $6$ points $D,E,F,G,H,I$ always determine an ellipse.**

[image]

How can I show this (likely obvious) result with a simple and compact proof?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the trivial question!

This problem is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2958405/559615).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing that the points in question lie on a common *conic* is straightforward.

I've renamed the points thusly: $D_B$ and $D_C$ are the points where the hyperbola through $A$ meets $\overline{BC}$; the subscripts indicate the closer vertex. Likewise for $E_C$, $E_A$, $F_A$, $F_B$.

[image]

Now, simply note that 
$$|BD_B| = |CD_C| \qquad |CE_C|=|AE_A| \qquad |AF_A| = |BF_B|$$
$$|D_BC| = |D_CB| \qquad |E_CA|=|E_AC| \qquad |F_AB| = |F_BA|$$
so that

> $$\frac{BD_B}{D_BC}\cdot\frac{CE_C}{E_CA}\cdot\frac{AF_A}{F_AB} = 
> \frac{CD_C}{D_CB}\cdot\frac{AE_A}{E_AC}\cdot\frac{BF_B}{FB_A} \tag{$\star$}$$

It happens that $(\star)$ holds if and only if $D_B$, $E_C$, $F_A$, $D_C$, $E_A$, $F_B$ lie on a conic. (This is the same condition used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959607/409), except that it really doesn't matter here if we consider the ratios as *signed* or *unsigned*.)

Showing that the conic is specifically an *ellipse* takes some extra work. I'll have to come back to that.